# Getting eth in the equation

Tags: symbols

I am trying to write a few physics equations in which I need the eth symbol and I am unable to write it on latex. I have tried to write it in a complicated way but it doesn't fit properly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}  
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\def\eth{{\specialfont\char238}}

\begin{document}
\section{Flux formula using GHP formalism}
Initial expression for the Flux 
\begin{equation}
F_{\xi} = - \frac{1}{32 \pi} \big[-u \chi N^{AB} N_{AB} + 2 u N^{AB} D_A D_B 
\chi + \chi N^{AB} C_{AB} + D^C \chi N^{AB} D_C C_{AB}
 + 2 N^{AB} C^C_{B} D_A D_C \chi \big]
\end{equation}

\noindent Using GHP derivatives and dyads on $S^2$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
N_{AB}&=& N \bar{m}_A \bar{m}_B + \bar{N} m_A m_B \\
C_{AB}&=& C \bar{m}_A \bar{m}_B + \bar{C} m_A m_B 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, we rewrite the flux in this formalism
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{\xi} &=& - \frac{1}{32 \pi} {[} -2 u \chi N \bar{N} + 2 u ( N 
\bar{\slashed{\partial}}^2 \chi + \bar{N} \slashed{\partial}^2 \chi - 2N 
\bar{\slashed{\partial}} \chi \bar{\sigma} - 2\bar{N} \slashed{\partial} \chi 
\sigma ) \\
 &&  +\chi \left(N\bar{C} + \bar{N}C \right) + \left(N\bar{C} 
\bar{\slashed{\partial}} \slashed{\partial} \chi + \bar{N} C 
\slashed{\partial} \bar{\slashed{\partial}} \chi \right) \\
 && 2 (N \slashed{\partial}\bar{C} \bar{\slashed{\partial}} \chi + \bar{N} 
\slashed{\partial}C \bar{\slashed{\partial}} \chi - 4 \sigma \bar{N} C 
\bar{\slashed{\partial}} \chi + N \bar{\slashed{\partial}} \bar{C} 
\slashed{\partial} \chi - 4 \bar{\sigma} \bar{C}N \slashed{\partial}\chi + 
\bar{N} \bar{\slashed{\partial}}C \slashed{\partial}   \chi   {]}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are loading `wasysym`, so you can get it with `\dh`. Note, however, that some might argue that your LaTeX commands could get modernized.

Comment: In equations, you may use `\text{\dh}`.

Comment: You set `\def\eth{{\specialfont\char238}}` in the preamble, but then don't use it anywhere in the body of the test document. This makes it well-nigh impossible to trace what may be going on. Please edit your query to demonstrate how you intend to use `\eth`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what your `\specialfont` is, but, generally, T1 encoded fonts have the eth.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{toneletters}{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{toneletters}{bold}{T1}{\familydefault}{bx}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol\ethm{\mathord}{toneletters}{"F0}

\begin{document}

$A+\ethm$

\boldmath $A+\ethm$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It’s also `"F0` in Unicode, so it might be worth mentioning that you could use very similar code with `TU` instead of `T1`.